# javascript/flash library for file upload with file size limit and progress bar

Tags: javascript, flash, file-upload, upload, uploadify

Is there any "mainstream" library used for this purpose? Commonly spread, well maintained, documented etc.
I found these (using flash):

- [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/) - not many releases, latest 12/2010, no documentation (!)
- [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/) - latest release 03/2010, documentation
- [fancyupload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/) - looks buggy.
- [phpfileuploader](http://phpfileuploader.com/) - looks heavyweight, and looks commercial (?) I cannot read the licence (you can download it but are you allowed to use it forever without paying?)
- [plupload](http://www.plupload.com)

New version of pure javascript (no flash) [Valums' ajax upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) claims to handle file size limit and progress bar, which is quite suspicious to me: these features require to guess the file size *before* the upload, which [seems impossible in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190934/getting-upload-file-size-before-upload) (look also [here](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/check-for-file-size-with-javascript-before-uploading.html)). Or can it work?

Comment: I took some tips from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4948008/684229

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Plupload](http://plupload.com/) and [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) look best up to my current research point...

I tried swfupload, it looked fine at the first sight but as I tried to use it, it started to be more and more cluttered, many of the features you see in the demo are unexpectedly *not* standard parts of the library, you have to get the example code and hack it a lot, it's not configurable (e.g. queue timeouts) etc... Refrained from using it.

Answer (score 1):

Check [jQuery-File-Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/). It's quite alright.  (Also handles file size. Thats what you mean?)

Comment: but this also doesn't use flash? How can it then assure to be able to gain the file size before upload, cross-browser, according to the links I posted at the end of my question?

Comment: The filesize is displayed in the Demo, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190934/getting-upload-file-size-before-upload) and [this](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/check-for-file-size-with-javascript-before-uploading.html) question states that it's impossible to do this in sole javascript cross-browser. So I guess either it might not work in all cases (browsers) or there is some contradiction between the questions I linked and this plugin being flawless...

Comment: Well, I can confirm that the plugin does not use flash. Other then that you might want to check the docs or leave a comment in the issue tracker. The project is very active...

Answer (score 1):

A new contender seems to be FileAPI, it uses HTML5 APIs, with flash as a fallback:
https://github.com/mailru/FileAPI

Here is an article about it on Smashing magazine: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/11/we-wanted-to-build-a-file-uploader/

Comment: +1 Thanks. I finally used plupload which works great for me and make my library wrapper around it, but I will keep this in mind if I design a new system :)